# Angular 10 Installing and running libraries issue

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library

My Angular App version is 10.4 version whenever I try to use a library like ngx-dropzone, ngx-file-drag-drop, ng2pdf viewer, or any other library I ran into issues it throws errors on compile time.

Here are the errors.

```
    ERROR in node_modules/@iplab/ngx-file-upload/lib/services/file-upload.service.d.ts:14:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/USER/Desktop/medic-cms/Medic-CMS/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

14     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<FileUploadService, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@iplab/ngx-file-upload/lib/services/file-upload.service.d.ts:15:22 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/USER/Desktop/medic-cms/Medic-CMS/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵInjectableDeclaration'.

15     static ɵprov: i0.ɵɵInjectableDeclaration<FileUploadService>;
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@iplab/ngx-file-upload/lib/components/file-upload-abstract.component.d.ts:30:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/USER/Desktop/medic-cms/Medic-CMS/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.

30     static ɵfac: i0.ɵɵFactoryDeclaration<FileUploadAbstract, never>;
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@iplab/ngx-file-upload/lib/components/file-upload-abstract.component.d.ts:31:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"C:/Users/USER/Desktop/medic-cms/Medic-CMS/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration'.
```

RightNow it is not possible for me to upgrade my angular version.

Comment: Try running ngcc in your project terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to dowload older versions of the libs, they are not compatible with your Angular 10.